# Hibernate-Validator 6.0.3Final compatible spring version

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator, bean-io

We are using hibernate validator version 5.1.3.Final with spring version 4.1.6.RELEASE to validate the input data along with bean-io framework.

Now we are planning to upgrade the hibernate validator to latest version to improve the performance of the workflow.

Kindly provide the compatible version of spring framework version with latest hibernate validator.

Thanks,
Chethan

Comment: The latest hibernate-validator version is 6.0.3-Final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Validator 6.0.x should be compatible with the version of Spring you are using and any further versions.

Just be careful about the dependencies as the groupId for Hibernate Validator has changed from org.hibernate:hibernate-validator to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator. So be sure you don't have both dependencies in your classpath.

And be careful to use validation-api 2.0.0.Final with it. It's an explicit dependency so it shouldn't be an issue but you might have overridden it somewhere.